# Monitoring SLA/SLO/SLI using Prometheus

Tags: performance, monitoring, performance-monitoring, grafana, prometheus

I have done much research about monitoring SLI metrics with Prometheus. I have found only how to monitor a cluster using Kubernetes. I'm hoping to find a response here for  simple monitoring.

I also want to know which is better for that using the R.E.D(rate,error,duration) method or the U.S.E(utilization,saturation,errors) method?

If possible give some examples(like : `1-clamp_max(sum(rate(wmi_cpu_interrupts_total[2m])),1)`)
For the 4 most standard metrics: CPU/DISKs/Networking/Memory